# Manual and automated calculation of false positive rate in confusion matrix do not agree

Tags: weka, false-discovery-rate, confusion-matrix

If my Weka confusion matrix looks like this:

```
               Predicted class

              A     B    C    D    E
              9     1    5    0    0  A
 Actual       0    25    4    0    7  B
 class        0     4   15    0   11  C
              0     0    0   15    0  D
              0     3    1    0   50  E
```

True positives for class B = 25.
False positives for class B: 1 + 4 + 3 = 8.
True negatives for class B: 9 + 15 + 15 + 50 = 89.
False negatives for class B: 4 + 7 = 11.

The true positive rate for class B: 25 / 36 = 0.694.
Yet Weka tells me that the false positive rate for class B is 0.070.

How? I cannot quite resolve this. My formula to calculate the false positive rate is FP / (FP + TN), i.e. 8 / 8 + 89 = 0.082.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True negatives for B requires both:

- predicted class $\neq$ B (i.e. result is negative)
- actual class $\neq$ B (i.e. negative result is true)

Sum up every entry in neither column B nor row B and you get the number of true negatives:
$$9 + 5 + 15 + 11 + 15 + 1 + 50 = 106$$

Then:
$$ \frac{8 }{8 + 106} = 0.0702$$

Comment: Thanks this makes sense. So my understanding of this is that if I have 36 NCA items, 4 are misclassified as SNT and 7 as EA. And 1 BFE, 4 SNT and 3 EA are misclassified as NCA.